# Broadcom wireless driver on Lenovo B590

Tags: wireless, drivers, 14.04, broadcom, lenovo

I've just bought a notebook Lenovo B590 with Windows 8 preinstalled. I tried the Live version of Ubuntu 14.04. The WiFi wasn't working, but I went on Additional Driver and I selected "Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcwl-kernel-source (proprietary)" and it worked correctly.
Then I installed Ubuntu 14.04, without partitions, I hadn't even activated Windows 8, and the WiFi wasn't working. I went on Additional Driver (this time in the Italian version) and I selected the same driver as before. Ubuntu asked me the password and at the end of the "applying changes" it deselected the Broadcom driver and automatically re-selected "Do not use the device".
The Live version still works.
Maybe are there any packages downloaded during the installation that do not work correctly with the Broadcom driver?
Can you help me, please?

Comment: Try with installing `firmware-b43-installer` driver installer.

Comment: Before we propose either the b43 firmware or Broadcom STA, we need to know about your exact device. Please edit your question to add the result of this from the terminal: lspci -nn -d 14e4: Thanks.

Comment: Hello, the exact device is: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01).
In the meantime I found a resolution for that.
Trying sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source I realized that I needed to download the bcmwl-kernel-source package. Then I connected my notebook via Ethernet, went to Additional Driver and re-selected the Broadcom driver. Now it works!
I hope someone else will find this useful.
Thank you for your kind answers. :-)

Comment: please copy that into "answer your own question", otherwise this still shows up as unanswered

Answer (score 1):

I copy the answer here. Sorry, I'm a newbie :-p

Hello, the exact device is: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01). In the meantime I found a resolution for that. Trying sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source I realized that I needed to download the bcmwl-kernel-source package. Then I connected my notebook via Ethernet, went to Additional Driver and re-selected the Broadcom driver. Now it works! I hope someone else will find this useful. Thank you for your kind answers. :-)